# Creating an array: text directly in source vs a string

Tags: bash

When the following code is executed, the output is what I expected it to be:

```
$ foo=(a b "c d") && for p in "${foo[@]}"; do echo $p; done
a
b
c d
```

But when the initializer comes from a string, for example like this:

```
$ foo=($(echo "a b \"c d\"")) && for p in "${foo[@]}"; do echo $p; done
a
b
"c
d"
```

so the output is different, while I expected those two commands to do the same. Why aren't the two ways equivalent, and how can I get the variant where the initializer comes from a string work the same way as direct initialization?

Comment: In the 2nd technique, the quotes are plain characters, not shell metacharacters. You'd need to mix an `eval` in there somewhere, which is generally not recommended.

Comment: @glennjackman So... are you telling me the answer is "you can't get that without shenanigans"? Also... why is it done that way?

Comment: How much do you trust the incoming string? `str='a b "c d"'; eval foo=($str); printf "%s\n" "${foo[@]}"`

Comment: @glennjackman I trust it as much as you can trust the output of `find` :D

Comment: @Griwes it's done that way because `echo "a b \"c d\""` produces the same output as `echo a b '"c' 'd"`'  and done this way `echo a b '"c'` does not cause a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
str='a b "c d"'
eval "foo=($str)"
printf "%s\n" "${foo[@]}"
```

I need to go take a shower now.